# How can I mention @everyone with a py-cord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

Running on py-cord 2.0.0, I am trying to have my bot send a message that mentions @everybody.

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

prefix = os.getenv('PREFIX')
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)

@ bot.slash_command(description="Test command, just sends a message where the user requested.")
async def say(ctx):
    UserNAME = ctx.author.name
    NickNAME = ctx.author.nick
    guildNAME = ctx.guild.name
    if ctx.user.nick:
        UserNAME = NickNAME
    await ctx.send(f"Hello! <@{ctx.author.id}>")
    await ctx.send(content=f"Hello! <@&915760331165429781>")

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

The bot sends both messages, but when it is sending the second message, it does not actually mention the everyone role. I get a message that is "Hello! @@everyone" and this does not function as a mention.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just have

```py
await ctx.send(content=f"Hello! @everyone")
```

Provided the bot has permissions to mention everyone then this should work. It's all I do in rare cases where I want my bots to tag the entire server.

Comment: Just a side note, the send function can send messages without entering the content argument. The string of your message can be inserted as the only argument in between the parentheses!